# Ajax json response of form submit: download file in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have asp web page responsible of uploading file using ajax.

the html code of the form is:

```
<form method="post" action="ajax/firmwareUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform" name="uploadform">
    <div class="left">
    <span id="lang502009" title="502009">Firmware File</span>:
        <input name="download image file" id="uploadfilename" type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div class="upload" id="uploadManual">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-blank" value="Upload"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the ajax code is :

```
 $("#uploadform").submit(function(e) {
     $.ajax({
     url:  'ajax/firmwareUpload',
     type: 'POST',
     data: new FormData(this),
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     success: function(data) {
         if (data.error) {
         $("body").load("subpage/upgradefail.asp");
         setTimeout(backToIndex, 5*1000);
         }
         else {
         var time = data.return;
         $("body").load("subpage/upgradewait.asp");
         setTimeout(backToIndex, time*1000);
         }
     },
     error: function(data) {
         alert("Operation could not be completed");
     }
     });
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

I tested this program in: firefox, chrome, opera, safari, IE11 and it's well working as wanted. so the server side can receive the response from the browser and the browser can receive the json response and display upgradewait.asp.

but if I test it with IE8 I can remark that the server can receive the request and do his job very well but when ie8 receive the json response it doesn't display upgradewait.asp and I get some download popup like that.
[image]

I downloaded this file and I found that its content is the json response.
In addtion I added some console.log and alert to success and error functions of ajax, and I found that it can't acces those response functions.

I make some searches in the internet about this problem. As a result what I understand is that IE8 has problems to understand the JSON message and I should modify the content type to somethings like text/html or application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. I tried that but any of those solution solved the problem.

have anyone an idea about this and can give a suggestion.